# Newly created method and layout shows 500 internal server error in cakephp 1.3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a controller courses where in I have created a new method list_arrangements.
I have also created a layout arrangements_list_layout.ctp inside layout folder under views.

Code:

```
 function list_arrangements(){
        $this->layout='arrangements_list_layout';

    }
```

When I call this layout or any other layout from this new method I get a 500 internal server error.But if I add an echo inside the method , it gets displayed correctly.
Inside arrangements_list_layout.ctp I have just added the code

```
<?php echo 'testt';?>
```

I have cleared the cache folder but the same error exists.
Please let me know if I have to do anything else.

Comment: your function must be public. try `public function list_arrangements()` and check once.

Comment: did you tried? also `on` your debug mode through `config.php (make it 2) `and check if any other error are also there. thanks.

Comment: `@Jitesh` did you tried what i said?

Comment: public or no visibility keyword doesn't matter! the main question is: what is the actual server error. You should use debug > 0 and you should take a look at the log files, what error is thrown. This is vital information and without it no one can really help you.

Comment: Error in apache --  Premature end of script headers: index.php